# The phrase うんやらかんやら?

Tags: phrases

What does this phrase mean and how would I use it? I saw it in a sentence but I couldn't figure out what it meant.

> 僕は赤の他人もいいところで**うんやらかんやら**。

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a variation form of [うんたらかんたら](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%86%E3%82%93%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89%E3%81%8B%E3%82%93%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89), which corresponds to 'yada yada' or 'blah blah' in English. It's used in place of something not very important to the speaker, or something too difficult to understand. In this case, the speaker thought the phrase following いいところで is obvious, and he was too lazy to say it.

Similar expressions include なんちゃらかんちゃら, なんたらかんたら, なんとかかんとか, なんちゃら, なんやかや and うんぬん.

Comment: Also どうたらこうたら, ああたらこうたら, どうのこうの, うんぬんかんぬん, ほにゃらら, yada yada yada...